# Not able to track enter key on input type = text

Tags: javascript, html

Can anybody tell me why is this not working?

```
  <input name ="txtChat" id ="txtChat" onkeydown ="isEnterPressed();"  type="text" style="width:720px;"/>
```

This is my javascript function :-

```
 function isEnterPressed(event){
                alert(event);

            }
```

On alert i always gets undefined :(

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in event type that is fired when the enter key is pressed, you need to check that in the `Event` object that is passed to the handler.

HTML:

```
<input name ="txtChat" id ="txtChat" onkeyup="onKeyPressed(event)"  type="text" style="width:720px;"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onKeyPressed(ev) {
   var e = ev || event;
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      //Enter was pressed
      return false; //prevents form from being submitted.
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob Relkin, now its working and enter key is captured. But i am facing another problem now. The page reloads as soon as i press enter key :(. Any idea, why is this happening? I have a `form` tag and this is causing problem. As soon as i remove it, it works fine. How do i get rid of this problem?

Comment: Yes, this is because the `form` is being submitted by default. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Great Jacob except that `return false` should be inside `e.keyCode` ;).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple inline check is:

```
<input name ="txtChat" id ="txtChat" onkeydown ="alert(event.keyCode == 13);"  type="text" style="width:720px;"/>
```

which outputs `true` if enter is pressed.